# ADB can't find Nexus 7 on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: android, adb, osx-mavericks, nexus-7

i have recently installed Mac OS X Mavericks and now adb can't detect my nexus 7 anymore. I've already tried to:

- Restart both pc and tablet
- add to adb_usb.ini the vendor's id
- switch from MTP to PTP and viceversa
- change usb port

I also noticed that Android File Transfer works perfectly.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: did you enable the developer settings?

Comment: In android? Yeah, the USB debug is checked!

Comment: did u use the adb devices to see if it shows up? is the server running

Comment: Yes, I killed and restarted the server several times, but the list is always empty. Before the update to Mavericks all was working!

Comment: the only thing that i can think of is that maybe you might require to install some drivers for the nexus 7

Comment: Yes, but USB drivers are not supported (nor required until Lion) in Mac OS

Comment: Did you accept the host machine for permission connect via USB debugging? Unplug the USB plug it back in and look at the display of the nexus 7, there should be a prompt to allow the computer with a given SHA to connect

Comment: Well the problem is that it doesn't ask me to accept the that permission. When I connect the tablet to the computer I can see on the nexus the notification about the USB debug and the connection type, but I can't do anything else

Comment: I can't explain why but now it does work. Maybe during thw night they decided that I can continue developing ;)
By the way thanks to you all guys for the advices!

Comment: did you get an answer to this? I have the same problem on 4.4.2

Comment: @Mike I know that this answer has no sense, but the problem solved by itself: the day after I started my PC and all was working. Don't know what happened..

Comment: @user2340612 Can you please post your answer or close this question?

Comment: @JaredBurrows well I have no answer: I tried many things, but the problem solved in some (unknown) way after some hours. The close "options" are not suitable (it's not a duplicate, or too broad..). Which one should I choose?

Comment: I'd post everything you tried for your trouble shooting. Obviously people like your question! Maybe they want to read your answer as well :)

Comment: @user2340612 I meant as an answer. This question has been unanswered for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

As told in the question I tried doing different things like rebooting the PC and the tablet but nothing happened.

I also tried switching off the "developer options" on my device and then turning it on again, but, again, no luck.

Maybe it can be useful to restart ADB server, with the following commands (via terminal):

```
[user]$ adb kill-server
[user]$ adb start-server (or adb devices)
```

Or from inside eclipse:

1. Open DDMS perspective
2. Click on the drop-down menu near the camera
3. Click on "restart ADB"

Eventually (some hours later) after some reboots and tricks like ADB has been able to recognize my device

Answer (score -1):

Just install USB driver for Nexus 7 in your PC & try refreshing hardware changes for the device in the device manager.

Comment: You should provide a link for a more helpful answer, especially since Google's documentation says you don't need a USB driver if you're on mac or linux - https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#InstallingDriver